# room/SQLite background scheduler/trigger that runs automatically

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room, scheduler, sqliteopenhelper

I've got a sample table:

[image: sampletable]

I have a Sample table which has a "creationDate" as an atribute. What I want is a way to increment(update) the "numOfTimesUpdated" attribute each 24h since the creationdate. so lets say "creationdate" is 01.01.2021 12:12 AM => numOfTimesUpdated=0, 02.01.2021 12:12 AM => numOfTimesUpdated=1, 03.01.2021 12:12 AM => numOfTimesUpdated=3.

How can I implement something like this in the best way?

Does SQLite has some kind of background scheduler/trigger where a UPDATE Query gets automatically called? Or Is my only chance the client side(application) using smth. like an ApplicationManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I implement something like this in the best way?
> You don't appear to even need a numberOfTimesUpdated column as the number of days since the creationDate can be calculated when required.

- If the date/time were stored in a supported format (e.g. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM) it is very simple.

For example consider this :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, creationdate TEXT);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
    (null,'myname','2021-01-02'),(null,'anothername','2021-03-03'),(null,'andanother','2021-06-06')
;
SELECT *,strftime('%s','now')/(60 * 60 * 24) - strftime('%s',creationdate)/(60 * 60 * 24) AS numOfTimesUpdated FROM table1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
```

It :-

1. Drops the table if it exists
2. Creates the table
3. Inserts 3 rows with creation dates (21st Jan 2021, 3rd March 2021 and 6th June 2021)
4. Extracts all of the rows **PLUS** a calculated column with the number of days since the creation date.
5. Cleans up the test environment by deleting the table.

The results as run on 13th June 2021 are :-

[image]

> Does SQLite has some kind of background scheduler/trigger where a UPDATE Query gets automatically called?

not time based.

> Or Is my only chance the client side(application) using smth. like an ApplicationManager?

Yes, but again you don't appear to need this.

**Working Room Example**

The following is a working room example that implements the SQLite example above: -

The **Table1** Entity :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "table1")
public class Table1 {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long id;
    String name;
    String creationDate;

    public Table1(){}
    @Ignore
    public Table1(String name, String creationDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }
}
```

- Note as in theory id's can be **long** long instead of int has been used. As long MUST have a value Long has been used to allow autogenerated id's (without the inefficient AUTOGENERATE).

A POJO **Table1WithNumberOfUpdates** to get the Table1 with the additional calculated column:-

```
public class Table1WithNumberOfUpdates {
    @Embedded
    Table1 table1;
    int numOfTimesUpdated;
}
```

A Dao **AllDao** to allow inserts and extracting a List of **Table1WithNumberOfUpdates** objects :-

```
@Dao
interface AllDao {

    @Insert
    long insert(Table1 table1);
    @Query("SELECT *, strftime('%s','now')/(60 * 60 * 24) - strftime('%s',creationdate)/(60 * 60 * 24) AS numOfTimesUpdated FROM table1")
    List<Table1WithNumberOfUpdates> getTable1WithNumberOfUpdatesList();
}
```

A standard @Database that returns an instance of the Database :-

```
@Database(entities = {Table1.class},exportSchema = false,version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDao getAllDao();

    private static volatile TheDatabase instance;

    public static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    TheDatabase.class,
                    "state.db"
            )
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

And finally some code in an Activity to add the three rows and extract the result outputting it to the log :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TheDatabase db;
    AllDao dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Instantiate Database and get dao
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getAllDao();

        dao.insert(new Table1("myname","2021-01-02"));
        dao.insert(new Table1("anothername","2021-03-03"));
        dao.insert(new Table1("andanothername","2021-06-06"));
        for (Table1WithNumberOfUpdates t: dao.getTable1WithNumberOfUpdatesList()) {
            Log.d("TABLE1INFO","Name is " + t.table1.name + " Created = " + t.table1.creationDate + " Updates Since Creation = " + t.numOfTimesUpdated);
        }
    }
}
```

**Result** :-

```
2021-06-14 10:17:44.498 D/TABLE1INFO: Name is myname Created = 2021-01-02 Updates Since Creation = 163
2021-06-14 10:17:44.499 D/TABLE1INFO: Name is anothername Created = 2021-03-03 Updates Since Creation = 103
2021-06-14 10:17:44.499 D/TABLE1INFO: Name is andanothername Created = 2021-06-06 Updates Since Creation = 8
```

- Days are 1 extra due to device using local time zone as opposed to the SQLite Tool used above (Navicat for SQLite).

Comment: thank you very much!!. the proposed solution would work. the solution would also mean that I only receive the data if I make a call. Let's say I want to keep an hardcore attribute "numOfUpdates" in the table, the only way to update the attribute is by some alarmmanager i guess? since, as you mentioned, sqlite does not support time based triggers unfourtantly

Comment: @FunnyMoments yep some external timer based event and a repeating alarm could be the way to go.